# Conditional Code Block

Tags: delphi

Anyone know a good solution or documentation for using conditional code blocks?

for Example If the code looks like...

DoSomethingImportant1, LoadData are functions with boolean results.

```
var 
 lOk: Boolean;
begin
 lOk := False;

 lOk := DoSomethingImportant1;

 if lOk then
 begin
  LoadData; 
  lOk := SaveData;
 end;


 DoSomethingwithSavedData1...
 DoSomethingwithSavedData2...

 if lOk then
  lOk := DoSomethingImportant2
 else GiveSpecificErrorAndExit;* 

 etc...
```

I don't want to save all the condtions if DoSomethingXX procedure occured 100 times..

Sorry for my Eng.

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if not DoSomething then
  raise Exception.Create('Error ...');

DoSomething2;    
DoSomething3;

if not DoSomething4 then
  raise Exception.Create('Error ...');

if not DoSomething5 then
  raise Exception.Create('Error ...');

DoSomething6;
DoSomething7;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with

```
begin
  if not DoSomethingImportant1 then
  begin 
    GiveSpecificErrorAndExit;*  
  end; 

  if LoadData and Save then
  begin
    DoSomethingwithSavedData1...
    DoSomethingwithSavedData2...
  end

  else
  begin
    GiveSpecificErrorAndExit;* 
  end;

  if not DoSomethingImportant2 then
  begin 
    GiveSpecificErrorAndExit;*  
  end; 

 etc...
```

If this is not the type of answer you are looking for, I will delete.